# Agrupar elementos com base em valores

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

JSON:

```
var obj = {
    'itemA' : {
        'x' : '300',
        'y' : '200'
    },
    'itemB' : {
        'x' : '305',
        'y' : '210'
    },
   'itemC' : {
        'x' : '442',
        'y' : '210'
    }
};
```

O que preciso fazer é pegar esses itens e ao invés de exibir os 3, exibir somente grupos que agrupam os itens próximo ao outro. Por exemplo, o `x` e `y` do **itemA** e **itemB** estão próximos então ao invés de exibir 2, exibiria só 1 agrupando. Já o **itemC** tem o `x` bem longe e o `y` próximo, mas como tem que ser o `x` e `y` que tem que estar perto, então exibiria ele sem agrupar com os outros, sendo assim exibiria 2 itens na tela.

Ainda não tenho noção de como fazer isso com `Javascript` ou `jQuery`, e até mesmo em `PHP` se for o caso, mas gostaria em JS/jQuery.

Comment: Primeiro teria que definir um limite de ate onde vai o "proximo", por exemplo se estiver 10% para mais ou para menos, logo o seu range seria, para o `itemA` de 270 ate 330.

Comment: Segunda etapa, defina como seria um item agrupado, pelo que entendi ,x e y sao as posicoes do elementos certo? Logo se estiverem proximos o que vai ser exibido na tela? _invés de exibir 2, exibiria só 1 agrupando_ ficou complicado por que nao da pra enteder exatamente o que vai fazer

Comment: Poderia ser algo de 20 no x e 20 no y (não porcentagem, mas valor mesmo)

Comment: Cada item tem o x e y. Eu quero agrupar os mais próximos em 1 só. Caso for muito longe, cria um novo grupo e assim por diante. O x e y são as bases pra verificar se está próximo ou não @NeuberOliveira